# Using Chef for setting Windows Active Directory GPO policies on domain controller

Tags: group-policy, chef, automation

I am looking to use Chef to automate the setting of active directory controlled group policy settings (typically on the primary PDC per forest).

I cant find any specific AD GPO functions, on the windows recipe [windows ad recipe](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows_ad) or [local policy recipe](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows-security-policy) are local security policies or joining of computers to domain - I cant find anything on the management of AD GPO.

Would this be a case of writing a recipe to set values stored in the central AD store as per http://techgenix.com/group-policy-settings-part1/? Or is this a really bad idea?

Alternatively can we run a utility to bring a known state (Powershell DSC) to the domain controller and simply overwrite what was there before? Can export https://github.com/microsoft/BaselineManagement, or powershell scripts for backup-gpo and restore-gpo.

Long story short we want a baseline set of windows AD policies that we apply as standard to all (independent separate forest) domain controllers when they come up out of the box, or are on-boarded as new managed infra, and updates to GPO from a single command across multiple servers in future.

Before i start doing this myself is this a bad idea (wrong tool for job), or reinventing the wheel (done before)?